# Query for finding Weighted Average in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a query where I would like to find the weighted average of some player data for an NBA player.

I have two fields for the average: a field named PIPM and Minutes. These two fields are in a table named Player_PIPM.

How would I write a query that would do the following: `SUM(PIPM * Minutes) / SUM of Minutes`

Example data:

```
+---------------+------+----------------+
| Player_Name   | PIPM | Minutes_Played |
+---------------+------+----------------+
| Stephen Curry | 1.61 |          671.6 |
| Stephen Curry | 0.07 |          139.4 |
| Stephen Curry |    7 |           3252 |
| Stephen Curry | 6.41 |         2172.8 |
| Stephen Curry | 8.32 |         3225.6 |
| Stephen Curry | 8.18 |           3302 |
| Stephen Curry | 8.14 |         3425.9 |
| Stephen Curry | 5.19 |         3129.7 |
| Stephen Curry | 2.85 |         3479.8 |
| Stephen Curry | 2.35 |          731.9 |
| Stephen Curry | 1.33 |         2490.5 |
| Stephen Curry | 0.12 |           2897 |
+---------------+------+----------------+
```

The weighted average of all of that data should come out to roughly 5.22

Edit: both fields are doubles

Comment: Please check the link. I think it will be helpful [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26234311/calculate-weighted-average-in-single-query)

Comment: @Linker I saw that post earlier and tried that but it keeps telling me there is an error in my syntax. I believe its because that post was for SQL Server and mine is in MySQL

Comment: Can you update your question with some sample data. Like Input table and output table. I would like to try it. :)

Comment: @Linker just did, there you go :)

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is code what I have tested for you. Test the query in [db-fiddle demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/neQ7KgtoikCM51HyNc27BC/1). Please check the link and answer it=>

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(Player_Name VARCHAR(200),PIPM  Float,Minutes_Played Float);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',1.61,671.6);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',0.07,139.4);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',7,3252);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry', 6.41,2172.8);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',8.32,3225.6);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',8.18,3302);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',8.14,3425.9);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',5.19,3129.7);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',2.85,3479.8);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',2.35,731.9);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',1.33,2490.5);
INSERT INTO MyTable Values ('Stephen Curry',0.12,2897);
                                                        
SELECT Player_Name, sum(PIPM * Minutes_Played) / sum(Minutes_Played) as WeightedAverage
from MyTable
group by Player_Name
order by Player_Name;
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Comment: Okay it worked but I am not sure why it did because it looks the same as the query I tested on my own earlier. Maybe I was accidentally misspelling something. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Well done @ParkerHarrelson123 . Finally your problem is solved. :-)